# Condensing a class

Tags: python, class, graph

I have hurriedly written this 'class' which  takes (for initialization) the textual representation of graph (as a string) and constructs a graph object.

The first line (header) describes the type of the graph and the number of vertices. It has two or three parts. The first part is either the character D indicating a directed graph, or the character U indicating an undirected graph. If the graph is weighted, the second part of the header is the character W. The last part of the header is a natural number n indicating the number of vertices in the graph. All the vertices in the graph are numbered from 0 to n-1.

If the graph string has more than one line, each remaining line (starting from the second line), describes an edge. The first two parts of an edge are two natural numbers between 0 and n-1, describing an edge between the two vertices identified with these numbers. If the graph is directed, the two numbers must be interpreted as an ordered pair describing an edge from the first vertex to the second vertex. If the graph is undirected, the two numbers must be interpreted as an unordered pair describing an edge between the two vertices. If the graph is weighted there will be a third part which will be an integer indicating the weight of the edge.

The graphs can be both directed or un-directed, and weighted or non-weighted

For example this graph:

```
graph_string = """\
D W 3
0 1 7
1 0 -2
0 2 0
"""
print(Graph(graph_string).adjacency_list)
```

is directed and weighted, and the '3' next to these symbolize the number of edges (in this case 3).

The adjacency_list of this example would output:

```
[[(1, 7), (2, 0)], [(0, -2)], []]
```

The 'class' I have written does achieve this, but not in the way a class is supposed to act. I am a bit confused about how to turn this into a proper class, all I know of now is that it should have only:

```
class Graph:
def __init__(self, graph_string):
    self.directed  =  # true if directed, false if un-directed
    self.weighted = # true if weighted, false otherwise
    self.adjacency_list = # a list of lists
```

as the **init**, with separate methods/functions to achieve the rest.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, and any feel free to ask questions as this was very difficult to word.

My Class:

```
class Graph:    
def __init__(self, graph_string):
    self.graph_string = []
    graph_string = graph_string.splitlines()
    for i in graph_string:
        i = (i.split())
        self.graph_string.append(i)
    first_num = self.graph_string[0]
    d_true = first_num[0]
    sec_num = self.graph_string[0]
    w_true = sec_num[1]
    self.weighted = w_true
    self.directed = d_true
    self.graph_string.pop(0)
    if self.directed == ("D"):
        self.directed = True
    elif self.directed == ("U"):
        self.directed = False
    if self.weighted == ("W"):
        self.weighted = True
    elif self.weighted != ("W"):
        self.weighted = False
    if self.weighted == False:
        var_num = graph_string[0]
        var_num = list(var_num)
        var_num = var_num[2]
        var_num = int(var_num)
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(var_num)]  
    elif self.weighted == True:
        var_num = graph_string[0]
        var_num = list(var_num)
        var_num = var_num[4]
        var_num = int(var_num)
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(var_num)]             
    if self.weighted == False:
        if self.directed == True:
            for s in self.graph_string:
                num_one = s[0]
                num_one = int(num_one)
                num_two = s[1]
                num_two = int(num_two)
                self.adjacency_list[num_one].append((num_two, None))
        elif self.directed == False:
            for t in self.graph_string:
                num_one = t[0]
                num_one = int(num_one)
                num_two = t[1]
                num_two = int(num_two)
                self.adjacency_list[num_one].append((num_two, None))
                self.adjacency_list[num_two].append((num_one, None))
    elif self.weighted == True:
        if self.directed == True:
            for t in self.graph_string:
                num_one = t[0]
                num_one = int(num_one)
                num_two = t[1]
                num_two = int(num_two)
                num_three = t[2]
                num_three = int(num_three)
                self.adjacency_list[num_one].append((num_two, num_three))
        if self.directed == False:
            for t in self.graph_string:
                num_one = t[0]
                num_one = int(num_one)
                num_two = t[1]
                num_two = int(num_two)
                num_three = t[2]
                num_three = int(num_three)
                self.adjacency_list[num_one].append((num_two, num_three))
                self.adjacency_list[num_one].append((num_one, num_three))        

    (self.adjacency_list)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Also, i would take a look at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ to help make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? It seems much easier and more generic if you used maps (however I transformed the map into a list as in your case).

Notes:
I don't know why the string should have the number of edges, I didn't use it. Also, notice that I didn't make any checks to see if the string is correctly formatted.

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, graph_string):
        elements = graph_string.split()
        self.directed = elements[0] == 'D'
        self.weighted = elements[1] == 'W'
        self.adjacency_list = []

        elements = elements[3:]

        graph_map = {}
        entries_per_line = 3 if self.weighted else 2
        elements = [elements[i:][:entries_per_line] for i in range(0,len(elements),entries_per_line)]
        for t in elements:
            lhs = int(t[0])
            rhs = int(t[1])
            if lhs not in graph_map:
                graph_map[lhs] = []
            if rhs not in graph_map:
                graph_map[rhs] = []
            val = (rhs, float(t[2])) if self.weighted else rhs
            graph_map[lhs].append(val) 
        for k in sorted(graph_map.keys()):
            self.adjacency_list.append(graph_map[k])


gs = """\
D W 3
0 1 7
1 0 -2
0 2 0
"""

print Graph(gs).adjacency_list
#[[(1, 7.0), (2, 0.0)], [(0, -2.0)], []]
```

Comment: You're not using the number of edges because you're not answering the original question :) If you were making a list of lists, you'd need to know the number of edges to correctly full out any trailing empty lists.